# Display JSON data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, callback

I am having a little bit of trouble here.  I have a call that returns some JSON, that is well-formed.  I checked it on JSON Lint.

```
JSON: {"facilities":[{"facilityId":"123","facilityName":"Pizza Hut"}]}
```

I am able to see that data in my alert box with this code:

```
 $(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        // TODO
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    $("#tags").focusout(function () {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert("Testing");
            },
            url: "FacilitiesAsync",
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I try this code I don't ever see the processFacilities function ever fire.  I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.  The $getJSON DOES work but the callback function is never executed.

```
   $.getJSON('FacilitiesAsync','sourceDb=sampleDb',processFacilities);
    function processFacilities(data) {
    var infoHtml = '';
    $.each(data, function(facilities, facilityInfo) {
        infoHtml += '<p>Facility: ' + facilityInfo + '<br></p>';
    }); // end of each

    $('#info').html(infoHtml);
};
```

I am not trying to run both of these at the same time.  I commented one out while I test the other.  These scripts are within a  block in my MVC4 application.

My div

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: How do you KNOW that it works? It seems it doesn't, or else that call would happen. What does you Network tab say?

Comment: I know the JSON is returned.  I have stepped through the code.  What I am seeing now is "Facility: undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `facilityName` inside the function. Try this:

```
   $.getJSON('FacilitiesAsync','sourceDb=IPACS',processFacilities);
    function processFacilities(data) {
    var infoHtml = '';
    $.each(data, function(facilities, facilityInfo) {
        infoHtml += '<p>Facility: ' + facilityInfo.facilityName + '<br></p>';
    }); // end of each

    $('#info').html(infoHtml);
};
```

Comment: I tried adding the facilityName property to the facilityInfo object and I still don't see anything in the UI.  I also added above my <div> where this should be shown.

Comment: Yea, I am not working on the autocomplete just yet.  That is the goal eventually.

Comment: No, I don't know what that is seattle

Comment: I am getting "Facility: undefined" rendered in the DIV when I add the facilityName to the facilityInfo object.

Comment: Yes, I have Skype but it is on my Mac, ugh

Comment: Seattle, you don't need to go to that much trouble.  Anyways, I don't have Skype on this machine.  Any idea why I would get undefined with that JSON string above?

Comment: I can't install anything right now on this machine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yea, forget the autocomplete function for now.  I am not concerned with it just yet.  I am doing a simple $getJSON() call passing in name of the function I want to call (in code-behind), with a parameter and a callback function.  Now I see the DIV tag render some data but that data is undefined.  I am working on my own machine here.  nothing remote.

Answer (score 0):

i think a mix of both will do it proper

:

```
        $("#tags").focusout(function () {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert("Testing");
            },
            url: "FacilitiesAsync",
            success: function(data) {
                  var infoHtml = '';
                  $.each(data, function(facilities, facilityInfo) {
                       infoHtml += '<p>Facility: ' + facilityInfo + '<br></p>';
                  }); // end of each

                  $('#info').html(infoHtml);
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
    });
});
```